# I can't remember... Who am I?

Tags: riddle

Don't step on me!

> A general wouldn't clean your shoes.

Though you can spell my name like that. Even lengthened it is not the way you'd expect.

Blinded and hung, you wouldn't expect much of me.
Not an author but a prince, Poe's got nothing on me.

**HINT 1**

> Wolves are the friends of a friend.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

> Dracula or Nosferatu or Vlad Tepes or Vlad the Impaler

Not sure about the first clues, which seem to refer to

> The don't tread on me snake on the flag from the American Revolutionary war, which might imply the general is General 'Wash'ington from the 'clean' reference. The link between a snake and Dracula seems to come through Harry Potter, as 'Voldemort' is an adaptation of Vladimir or Waldemar (all meaning 'ruler'), and Voldemort is a snake in the Harry Potter series.

The blinded and hung seem to refer to

> a bat

and prince could refer to

> Prince of Wallachia

and Poe could be a reference to

> the horror genre.

Hint 1 could refer to

> Wolfman or the line from Stoker, 'Listen to them, the children of the night. What music they make!'

Comment: Sorry but that's an interesting idea,  but not the answer I am looking for.